# Blazor Web Assembly Project Not running in Browser (Edge/Chrome/IE)

Tags: blazor

I am trying to execute the Blazor WebAssembly Standalone project in Edge, suddenly this project is producing the following error

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

One or more errors occurred.

Failed to launch debug adapter.  Additional information may be available in the output window.

### Unable to launch browser: "Could not connect to debug target at http://localhost:1051: Could not find any debuggable target"

### OK

I have tried the solution suggested on [one or more errors occurred failed to launch debug adapter Visual Studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65230472/one-or-more-errors-occurred-failed-to-launch-debug-adapter-visual-studio-2019)
But it is not working.

Can anybody help me on this?
Thanks in advance

Regards
Mahesh[image]

Comment: Restarted VS already?

Comment: Do you have a local firewall enabled?  The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#firewall-configuration) highlight that as a possible problem.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the computer (the VS restart is not enough).

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem as illustrated above, but only with VS2022. "Failed to launch debug adapter. ... Unable to attach to browser".  I was using Chrome Version 103.0.5060.114 (Official Build) (64-bit).

[image]

When I go back to VS2019, the sample Blazor project from udemy works as expected.  Same SLN file, same folder just opened with VS2019.

[image]

VS2019 differences from VS2022 were in the installer "individual components". Even when I added .NET5 and Core 3.1 back into VS2022, still the problem illustrated above.

I do not understand why a Blazor solution needs .NET5 when VS Installer is clear that .NET5 is "out of support".  This is the .csproj of the sample solution from udemy:

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="compilerconfig.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="compilerconfig.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="5.0.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Or, how is VS2019 different from VS2022 in the context of Blazor.

VS2019:
[image]

VS2022:
[image]